# Create a PyCharm configuration that runs a module a la "python -m foo"

Tags: python, pycharm

My python entrypoint needs to be run as a module (not a script), as in:

```
python -m foo.bar
```

The following does not work (and is not supposed to):

```
python foo/bar.py
```

How can I create a run confirguration in pycharm that runs my code using the first invokation above?

Comment: Discussion on JetBrains support forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206603365-debug-a-run-configuration-with-a-package-module-instead-of-script

Comment: There is now [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51268846/1953800) that would probably help more people if accepted.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In 2018.1 it is finally possible to specify the module name instead of the script path in the UI. There is a dropdown for changing it, to the left of the input field.

[image: PyCharm Run Configuration]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @alexflint I suggest you change the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure you set the correct working directory

Answer (score 44):

There is a workaround I use for my scripts, which do use relative imports.

python -m actually invokes a script called runpy.py which is part of a standard Python installation. These two invocations are equivalent:

```
python -m my_module.a.b module_arguments
python python_lib_directory/runpy.py my_module.a.b module_arguments
```

Use the latter method to setup your Run/Debug Configuration:

**Script:** python_lib_directory/runpy.py

**Script parameters:** my_module.a.b module_arguments

**Interpreter options:** (leave blank, no -m required)

Comment: Great trick, this also enables you to use the profiling option of pycharm !

Comment: This still wouldn't work for me. I still got the error: couln't find module. Can it have something to do with the fact that I'm using Conda to manage environments (including PyCharm)?

Comment: For PyCharm 2017.3.2 (Professional Edition), @andrewdotn's answer can work for `Run` but not for `Debug`. You answer can work for both `Run` and `Debug`.

Comment: In my Ubuntu installation, the script is located there: ```./usr/lib/python*/runpy.py```

Comment: What if I want to debug algo2.py?  
`C:\Python36\Scripts\pylivetrader.exe run algo2.py`

Answer (score 31):

According to `man python`, the `-m` option

> **-m module-name**
>          Searches  sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.

So most of the time you can just right-click on `bar.py` in the Project tool window and select `Run bar`.

If you really need to use the `-m` option, then specify it as an Interpreter option, with the module name as the Script in the Edit Configurations dialog:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm using "from __future__ import absolute_import" and then later I do "from . import foo".

Comment: Oh, ok. I’ve updated the answer to handle that case.

Comment: Any chance of running this from a remote interpreter?

Comment: That worked for running the module, but not when debugging it. If I click the debug icon instead of the run icon, I get the error No module found.

Comment: This works when just running the application. Profiling however fails
with a "Import by filename is not supported."

In order to get profiling to work you need the 'runpy.py' trick below

Comment: If you are using `__main__.py` as module file you may need to add it as part of the script (as in `foo.baz.__main__`) even if it's not needed with a regular `python -m` execution.

Answer (score 8):

## IntelliJ IDEA / PyCharm 2017

Field "Script" is optional in the recent versions of JetBrains IDEs. Specifying `-m foo.bar` in "Script parameters" is enough:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a great update. This should be the new accepted answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in PyCharm 2017.3.1 (Professional Edition), apparently because PyCharm actually calls `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py ` with lots of options, including `--file XXX` which it sees as `--file -m` using your solution.

Answer (score 4):

In PyCharm 2016 specifying `-m` without a script path doesn't work, as they use a wrapper script that doesn't accept the `-m` argument.

Here's my solution, which works for run & debug configurations: https://github.com/amnong/misc/tree/master/pycharm_runner

Edit: I just read J. R. Petrus's comment, and my solution is very similar. BTW I also tried to support proper entry points using `pkg_resources`, but for some reason `pkg_resources.load_entry_point()` could not find my project's distribution...