# Create a PyCharm configuration to run a python script on a file?

Tags: python, pycharm

[Create a PyCharm configuration that runs a module a la "python -m foo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081065) shows how to create a PyCharm configuration to run a module by clicking on the module.   But how does one create a configuration to run a module by clicking on a file to be processed by that module?

The Grako compiler is run from the command line as:

$ python -m grako foo.ebnf -o foo.py

The grammar file `foo.ebnf` is in my working directory, and when I click on the grammar file, I want python to run the grako module to compile it into `foo.py`.
Creating a special purpose run configuration that works only on `foo` is easy enough:

[image: PycharmRunConfig]

but how does one create a configuration that when you right click on any file it will show a context menu item to run the module on that file?  Normally that is done with something like a %s parameter to specify the filename, but how do you configure PyCharm to display a context menu Run and recognize a filename substitution that works for whatever file the user has selected?