# Profiling module in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, profiling

Following up on this question:
[Create a PyCharm configuration that runs a module a la "python -m foo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081065/create-a-pycharm-configuration-that-runs-a-module-a-la-python-m-foo)

Running and debugging modules works great for me with the new option from 2018.1, for which you can now specify a module to run. However, profiling the same configuration does not work.

PyCharm tries to run something like this:

```
/path/to/python /path/to/pycharm/plugins/python/helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py 127.0.0.1 44725 -m mypackage.cli.runthis paramA paramB
```

For whatever reason, all parameters (especially the -m) are forwarded to my package, and argparse complains that it doesn't know -m. As I said before, this configuration works perfectly fine for running/debugging. Any idea how I could get the profiler working?